# How does /bin/bash -c differ from executing a command directly?

Tags: bash

I'm curious why the commmand:

```
for f in `/bin/ls /mydir | sort | tail -n 10`; do echo $f; done;
```

Outputs the last ten files in /mydir, but

```
/bin/bash -c "for f in `/bin/ls /mydir | sort | tail -n 10`; do echo $f; done;"
```

Outputs "syntax error near unexpected token '[file in /mydir]'"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using double-quotes, so the parent shell is interpolating backticks and variables before passing the argument to `/bin/bash`.

Thus, your `/bin/bash` is receiving the following arguments:

```
-c "for f in x
y
z
...
; do echo ; done;"
```

which is a syntax error.

To avoid this, use single quotes to pass your argument:

```
/bin/bash -c 'for f in `/bin/ls /mydir | sort | tail -n 10`; do echo $f; done;'
```

Comment: By chance, this answer helped me solve a strange error (Deployment/Capistrano/Composer/etc.), root cause: double quotes vs. single quotes in a command that got pieced together automatically somewhere down the line. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Different newline handling in your subcommand output.  For example on my machine, using `/bin` I get this output for your first example:

```
rmdir
sh
sleep
stty
sync
tcsh
test
unlink
wait4path
zsh
```

But with the latter:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `sh'
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: `sh'
```

Because the command substitution takes place in your *first* shell in both cases, your first one works (the newlines are stripped out when making the command line), but in the second case it doesn't - they remain in the string thanks to your `""`.  Using `echo` rather than `bash -c` can showcase this:

```
$ echo "for f in `/bin/ls /bin | sort | tail -n 10`; do echo \$f; done"
for f in rmdir
sh
sleep
stty
sync
tcsh
test
unlink
wait4path
zsh; do echo $f; done
```

You can see from that what your `bash -c` is seeing and why it doesn't work - the `sh` comes before the `do`!

You can use single quotes instead, but that will cause the subcommand to run in your new subshell:

```
$ /bin/bash -c 'for f in `/bin/ls /bin | sort | tail -n 10`; do echo $f; done'
rmdir
sh
sleep
stty
sync
tcsh
test
unlink
wait4path
zsh
```

If that's not ok, you need to get rid of those newlines:

```
$ /bin/bash -c "for f in `/bin/ls /bin | sort | tail -n 10 | tr '\n' ' '`; do echo \$f; done"
rmdir
sh
sleep
stty
sync
tcsh
test
unlink
wait4path
zsh
```