# Environment variables in Google Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

We want to migrate from Bitbucket Pipelines to Google Cloud Build to test, build and push Docker images.

How can we use environment variables without a CryptoKey? For example:

```
- printf "https://registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}\nregistry=https://registry.npmjs.org" > ~/.npmrc
```

Answer (score 6):

To use environment variables in the `args` portion of your build steps you need:

- "a shell to resolve environment variables with $$" (as mentioned in the example code [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials#example_build_request_using_an_encrypted_variable))
- and you also need to be careful with your usage of quotes (use single quotes)

See below the break for a more detailed explanation of these two points.

While the [Using encrypted resources](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials) docs that David Bendory also linked to (and which you probably based your assumption on) show how to do this using an encrypted environment variable specified via `secretEnv`, this is not a requirement and it works with normal environment variables too.

In your specific case you'll need to modify your build step to look something like this:

```
# you didn't show us which builder you're using - this is just one example of
# how you can get a shell using one of the supported builder images

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'printf "https://registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=%s\nregistry=https://registry.npmjs.org" $$NPM_TOKEN > ~/.npmrc']
```

Note the usage of `%s` in the string to be formatted and how the environment variable is passed as an argument to `printf`. I'm not aware of a way that you can include an environment variable value directly in the format string.

Alternatively you could use `echo` as follows:

`args: ['-c', 'echo "https://registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$${NPM_TOKEN}\nregistry=https://registry.npmjs.org" > ~/.npmrc']`

---

**Detailed explanation:**

My first point at the top can actually be split in two:

1. you need a shell to resolve environment variables, and
2. you need to escape the `$` character so that Cloud Build doesn't try to perform a substitution here

If you don't do 2. your build will fail with an error like: *Error merging substitutions and validating build: Error validating build: key in the template "NPM_TOKEN" is not a valid built-in substitution*

You should read through the [Substituting variable values](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values) docs and make sure that you understand how that works. Then you need to realise that you are *not* performing a substitution here, at least not a Cloud Build substitution. You're asking the shell to perform a substitution.

In that context, 2. is actually the only useful piece of information that you'll get from the [Substituting variable values](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values) docs (that `$$` evaluates to the literal character `$`).

My second point at the top may be obvious if you're used to working with the shell a lot. The reason for needing to use single quotes is well explained by [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167803/how-does-bin-bash-c-differ-from-executing-a-command-directly) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711970/i-cant-seem-to-use-the-bash-c-option-with-arguments-after-the-c-option-st) questions. Basically: "You need to use single quotes to prevent interpolation happening in your calling shell."

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like you want to use Encrypted Secrets: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials

Comment: As I mentioned, I didn't want to use KMS, encrypted secrets. But seems like is not possible without it.

Comment: I may not be understanding your question; note that you can pass environment variables into your build steps (`env`): https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#Build.BuildStep

Comment: I think @NuruddinIminokhunov wants to be able to do something like:

` - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm', env: NPM_TOKEN: 'my_token'`